# Unable to run ab initio graph on putty server by using .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I m trying to automatically run a `ab initio gde graph` on putty server by running a bat file on windows

In the `bat` file I have coded as below,

```
@echo on
Start C:\Users\Desktop\Putty  awitab8d@awit.wload.bank.co.uk -pw passwd -m C:\Users\Desktop\command.txt
```

In the command file I have written

```
cd  \path\  

air sandbox run graph.mp
```

I'm trying to login into `ab initio` server and execute this graph.

When I do this, the graph is not executed and error comes up as

> 'air not found'

When I login into putty manually and manually run the graph, the graph execute successfully

My question is why air not found error comes up when running the graph using `.bat` file

Comment: this is not a problem with your bat file, but with your putty command file, or more probably with your SSH server program, what is it?

Comment: Yes     i m logging into ab intio backend server  and trying to run a graph using air command    but its showing tjat air not found       on doing the same thing manually evrythng is working fine

Comment: "Doing the same thing" what is this "same" thing? Typing the putty command?

Comment: yes when i manually login into putty and i ru the graph as air sandbox run graph.mp by tying it   the graph runs   but when i execute the bat file air not found error comes up